# Breadth first search: shortest reach hackerrank

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

Given an undirected graph consisting of N nodes (labelled 1 to N) where a  node S represents the start position and an edge between any two nodes is of length 6 units in the graph. Problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach).

It is required to calculate the shortest distance from start position (Node S) to all of the other nodes in the graph.

Solution: This clearly is an application of floyd algorithm for minimum distances.

What I've tried: I have tried below code and it is passing 2 testcases but failing in all other test cases. I am at my wits end as to the sneaky bug. I just want hint towards the solution. It would be nice to provide hints to other ways to solve this with respect to complexity but I am looking for a sneaky bug with the current code.

```
def short_paths(cost, nodes):
for i in range(1, nodes):
  for j in range(1, nodes):
    for k in range(1, nodes):
      if cost[i][j] > cost[i][k]+cost[k][j]:
        cost[i][j] = cost[i][k]+cost[k][j]
return cost

tests = int(input())
while tests:
  x = input().split(" ")
  nodes, edges = int(x[0]), int(x[1])
  #initialize everything with infinity
  dp = [[1<<31 for i in range(nodes+1)] for i in range(nodes+1)]
  #distance between self is 0
  for i in range(nodes+1):
    dp[i][i] = 0
  while edges:
    p = input().split(" ")
    x, y = int(p[0]), int(p[1])
    #undirected graph
    dp[x][y] = 6
    dp[y][x] = 6
    edges -= 1
  src = int(input())
  dp = short_paths(dp, nodes+1)
  result = []
  for i in range(1, nodes+1):
    if src != i:
      if dp[src][i] == 1<<31:
        result.append("-1")
      else:
        result.append(dp[src][i])
  print(" ".join(str(e) for e in result))
  tests -= 1
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use Floyd-Warshall? That's a solution for the *all-pairs* shortest paths problem in a weighted graph where edges can have different weights, and where edge weights can even be negative. It's complete overkill and really slow. The problem even says breadth-first search in the title; that was a clear hint to use breadth-first search. (Also, the problem in the link gives all edges weight 6, not 66.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will use that but wondering why the existing solution fails to provide the answer. Where did you see 66?

Comment: Your question says "an edge between any two nodes is of length 66 units". The link says something different.

Comment: @user2357112 modified. Thanks.

Comment: What's up with all the occurrences of `nodes+1`?

Comment: @user2357112 that is because nodes are from 1 and not 0. So just making sure it runs up till nodes.

Comment: Then what's up with all the *non*-occurrences of `nodes+1` in `short_paths`?

Comment: It is passed already as nodes +1 as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem in these lines:

```
for i in range(1, nodes):
  for j in range(1, nodes):
    for k in range(1, nodes):
```

You should iterate over k first in order for the result to be correct:

Try:

```
for k in range(1, nodes):
  for i in range(1, nodes):
    for j in range(1, nodes):
```

As the DP uses previous results it turns out that the order of the iteration is crucial to get the correct results.

The way I remember the order is to think that the k^th iteration of the algorithm computes the shortest path from i to j using just intermediate nodes just from positions 1 to k.

However, for this problem this O(N^3) approach will timeout.  A better approach is to perform a breadth first search from the starting location which will have complexity of N+M instead.

Comment: Nope, check the value I am passing to this function

Comment: You are right - I've proposed an alternative correction

Comment: Sorry but I am afraid, how is this different ?

Comment: Yes but I am not getting timed out. Just that the answers are not matching. I will use BFS anyway but just out of curiosity what is wrong with current solution using Floyd ?

Comment: I believe the only problem is the order of iteration.  Have you tried it with the variables in the order I suggested?

Comment: sorry but that makes no sense. i, j and k is iterating from 1 to nodes in your case as well as in my case. Anyway will give it a try.

Comment: wow it passed all the test cases but wondering what is the difference? I just changed the order and it worked. How? If you can put the explanation then i will mark this answer correct.

Comment: Consider the shortest path between 1 and 2.  Your ordering works DP[1][2] out very early on in the algorithm but only considers paths that involve one intermediate node, so it will fail if the true shortest path involves more nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import queue 

def BFS(s):
    q = queue.Queue()
    q.put(s)
    visited[s] = True
    dist[s] = 0

    while not q.empty():
        u = q.get()
        for v in graph[u]:
            if not visited[v]:
                visited[v] = True
                q.put(v)
                dist[v] = dist[u] + 1

Q = int(input())
for _ in range(Q):
    n, m = map(int, input().split())

    graph = [[] for i in range(n)]
    visited = [False for i in range(n)]
    dist = [-1 for i in range(n)]

    for i in range(m):
        u, v = map(lambda x: int(x) - 1, input().split())
        graph[u].append(v)
        graph[v].append(u)
    s = int(input()) - 1

    BFS(s)
    for i in range(n):
        if i == s:
            continue
        print(dist[i]*6 if dist[i] != -1 else '-1', end = ' ')
    print()
```

Just use normal BFS